# Android app crashing with message incorrect google play services version

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to fetch the advertising ID in-app. The app crashes at that point with the following crash message :

> Caused by com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesIncorrectManifestValueException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 1XXXXXXX but found 4YYYYYY.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:     
> at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:32)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:2)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@@17.1.0:7)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@@17.1.0:3)
> at com.caratlane.android.activity.MainApplication$2.doInBackground(MainApplication.java:236)
> at com.caratlane.android.activity.MainApplication$2.doInBackground(MainApplication.java:231)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

I have verified that the below meta-data is present within the application tag

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

What I tried but didn't solve the issue :

1. Adding permission advertising ID
2. Adding the version value directly

Comment: We had this crash for months until we found one of our internal libs overriding this integer and setting an old one. We removed the declaration in the lib and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

**From google play console**

Apps that use advertising ID and target Android 13 or later must declare the `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` permission in their app manifest. If you don't include this permission, your advertising identifier will be zeroed out; any attempts to access the identifier will receive a string of zeros instead of the identifier.

More Information

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en

Comment: would this crash the app though? The ad id should be 0. The error message says version number doesn't match

Comment: I added the permission but still the app is crashing